# How do I delete these partitions on my iMac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-format

How do I delete the disk0s2 partition (see below) on my iMac's internal drive??

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD                      198.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s4
   4:                  Apple_HFS Macontish HD            391.0 GB   disk0s5
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data OSXRESERVED             8.0 GB     disk0s7
   7:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                401.0 GB   disk0s8

/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         24.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X Basic          23.0 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot                         650.0 MB   disk1s3
```

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by doing this? It is surrounded by other partitions so it won't be available to combine with your MacHD, you can't combine it with the EFI partition, though you *might* be able to combine it with disk0s4.

Comment: What is a "Microsoft Basic Data" partition type? I've never heard of that, does that just mean it's FAT or NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

If you boot up off the Recovery Partition (or internet recovery), you can fire up Disk Utility and use it's Partitioning tool to delete that partition and grow your Macintosh HD.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the Disk Manager app and recovery partition soon?

Maybe the graphic disk manager from the fedora installer pendribe could help you